# Problem with the saddle point theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Okay, the theorem's name isn't "saddle point theorem", But I have found some arguments in my book that states the following :

Let $f$ be a function of two variables such that $f:R^2->R$. For a point $p_o$ to be a maximum or minimum point  The argument :
$$f_1(p_o)≤0\\f_2(p_0)≤0$$

is necessary. Okay So my first question arises here. Okay We are definitely sure that it's a necessity. But The argument means that at $p_0$ we shouldn't be able to see an increase in the value of $f$ in the directions $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Would "not seeing an increase in $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$" imply "not seeing an increase in any direction since these two vectors make up the whole space". Can anyone give a formal proof?

Okay The main problem is here
.The following argument is given :
"A simple condition which is sufficient to ensure that a critical point $p_0$ be a saddle point is that $f_{11}(p_0)f_{22}(p_0)<0$" Okay this makes sense. But then why do we need to use the theorem below :?

let $\delta = (f_{12}(p_0))^2-f_{11}(p_0)f_{22}(p_0)$ if $\delta>0$ then $p_0$ is a saddle point for $f$.

I've proved this theorem and, yes it is sufficient but why not the other argument?

Comment: Your notation is terrifying.  What are those subscripts?

Comment: @lordoftheshadows If you feel like something is "terrible" you can edit. Commenting here doesn't contribute anything - 
However I would have appreciated a comment "Subscripts look nasty, you need to be careful when doing this instead you can do that" etc.

Comment: I apologize fr being rude but your notation is not standard.  What do the subscripts mean?

Comment: If $f$ is *differentiable* at $p_0$, then vanishing partial derivatives is sufficient to ensure that there’s no increase “in any direction.” On the other hand, there are many examples of non-differentiable functions for which the partial derivatives exist and are zero. Also, for a formal argument you’ll need to sharpen what you mean by “in any direction” since there are also functions for which all of the directional derivatives exist and are zero, but are still not differentiable: you need to consider *all* trajectories that lead to $p_0$, not only straight lines.